# React native Google pay not working on real device

Tags: react-native, react-native-google-pay

After coding a payment page and integrating react-native-google-pay, it work well on Android emulator but those not work on real device.

Please I need help on this

Comment: Make sure you have done all the necessary production release configs

Comment: Found this issue ticket https://github.com/sorokin0andrey/react-native-google-pay/issues/30 might be helpful